# Workflow status page

Tags: workflow, error

suddenly workflow status page of 90% projects in project center show "sorry, someyhing went wrong"
When i checked the ULS logs i found : "value connot be null"

Is there any solution !

---

```
Application error when access Llayouts/15/12r. Error.value connot be null. 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.retrieveSchema(Schema schemalndex) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.retrieveSchemaGuid(Schema schemalndex) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkilow.get_Associationldl) Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.GetReadOnlyParentAssociation() 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workilow.SPWorkflow.get_ParentAssociationl) 
at ASP._layouts_15_wrkstat_aspx._Render_contro16(HtmITextWriter _w. Control parameterContainer) 
at System.Web.ULControl.RenderChildrenIntemal(HtmlTedWriter writer. Collection children) a System.Web.ULControl.RenderControlIntemal (HtmlTextWriter writer. ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.ULControl.RenderChildrenIntemal(HtmlTextWriter writer. Collection children) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDettaRenderChildren(HtmITextWater output) at System.Web.U1WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmITedWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmITedWriter writer) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AiaxDeka.Render(HtmlThdWriter writer) 
at System.Web.ULControl.RenderControlIntemal(HtmITedWriter writer. ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.ULControl.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTedWriter writer. Collection children) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmIControls.HtmlForrn.RenderChildren(HtmITedWriter writer) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmIControls.HtmIContainerControl.Render(HtmITextWriter writer) at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SharePointForrn.Render(HtmITextWriter output) at System.Web.ULControl.RenderControlIntemal(HtmITedWriter writer. ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.ULControl.RenderChildrenIntemal(HtmlTextWiiter writer. Collection children) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmIControls.HtmIContainerControl.Render(HtmITedWriter writer) at System.Web.ULControl.RenderControlIntemal(HtmITedWriter writer. ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.ULControl.RenderChildrenIntemal(HtmlTedWriter writer. Collection children) 
at System.Web.ULControl.RenderControlIntemal(HtmlfextWriter writer. ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.ULControl.RenderChildrenIntemal(HtmlTextWriter writer. Collection children) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) a System.Web.ULPage.Render(HtmITedWriter writer) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter writer) at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render (HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.ULControl.RenderControlIntemal(HtmITextWriter writer. ControlAdapter adapter) 
at System.Web.ULPage.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint. Boolean includeStagesPiterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Please post more details. This isn't enough to solve the issue.

Comment: when i try to access to the workflow status page (site workflow on project server developped with sharepoint designer) it shows "sorry, someyhing went wrong"  and a correlation ID. i took the id and got the error below on the ULS logs

Comment: It looks like the page itself may be corrupted. I would try recreating it.

Comment: Is there any solution !